# Printing a non-english language in WGL

Tags: opengl, wgl

I want to print out words in languages other then english (such as russian and german) while using WGL.

I use the same technique that was described in http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/bitmap_fonts/17002/ for printing english, but the same technique is not useful when using russian, it simply does'nt print the russian letters, only numbers.

Is there a possible solution?

**SOLVED**

Solved by changing

```
    base = glGenLists(96);
...
    wglUseFontBitmaps(hDC, 32, 96, base );
```

to

```
   base = glGenLists(1600);
...
    wglUseFontBitmaps(hDC, 32, 1600, base );
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `CreateFont` specify a different character set identifier than `ANSI_CHARSET` in your case it should probably be `RUSSIAN_CHARSET`

Comment: Are you still using vsprintf to print the characters or did you change it to the wide character version?